# Failed to resolve component <router-view> VueRouter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have a project build with `Vue.js 3.2.13` and `Vue-Router 4.0.14`. I think I do everything right but the browser raises an error "[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: router-view
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
at "

My `router.js` file:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "index",
    component: () => import("@/views/HomePage.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/signin",
    name: "signin",
    component: () => import("@/views/SignIn.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/signup",
    name: "signup",
    component: () => import("@/views/SignUp.vue"),
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

My `main.js` file;

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";


import { router } from "./router";


createApp(App).component("fa", FontAwesomeIcon).use(router).mount("#app");
```

Additionally App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HeaderNavbar />
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I run the project I get the warning on browser console:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: router-view
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem in your case is exporting `router` as `default` from `router.js` but importing it as named import in `main.js`.

Therefore, replacing

```js
import { router } from "./router"; // ❌
```

with

```js
import router from "./router"; //
```

will make VueRouter work as expected. (I doubt routing currently works in your project. It shouldn't.)

---

Alternatively, adding a named export of `router` to `router.js` (and keeping the current import syntax in `main.js`) would also make the problem go away.
You can do that by adding `export`  in front of `const router = createRouter(/* etc... */`, in that file. If you do this, `export default router` becomes obsolete (unused).

Answer (score 0):

try make install vue-resource

```
npm install vue-resource
```